# How to wait for initialization to complete before returning a singleton instance in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a singleton class, which requires a network operation with asynchronous callback to initialize. Any member function of that class should only be called when initialization callback finished.

What I'm not clear with, is how to wait for asynch callback to finish before I return a singleton instance to a caller? Or maybe is there any other way to ensure initialization completes before any function can be called (only initialization should be sequential, all operations after that shouldn't be).

Here's the minimal code:

```
class DataProvider {

    public static let instance: DataProvider {
        // on first call wait here until callback is done
        // on subsequent calls, no need to wait since already initialized
        return internalInstance
    }

    private static let internalInstance = DataProvider()

    private init() {
        initialize()
    }

    private func initialize() {
        Something.callAsynch { (result, error) in
            // instance becomes ready when this line is executed
        }
    }

    public func doSomething() {
        // this function should only run after asynch callback was executed
    }
}
```

This class is called by other classes and potentially other threads like this:

```
DataProvider.instance.doSomething()
```

Comment: @George_E I am familiar with them in general, just not sure how to use them in this case. If you have a specific idea, please post, even a gist will do

Comment: The simplest solution would be to pass a closure as a parameter to `doSomething`. While your resource is loading you store the closures in an array. When it's done you call all the closures with the resource. After that you can execute any calls to `doSomething` immediately

Comment: @KirilS. Must have not fully understood the question, sorry!

Comment: A second solution would be to use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter)

Comment: @AugustoDiasNoronha in both cases it pushes responsibility of synchronization to the callers. I was trying to avoid this, since this class only needs to be asynchronous once (on initialization), later it just holds to that static data. I was planning to do initialization early, minimizing the chances that caller needs to wait.  So making callers (and there's up to 5 of them) dance around this asynch init problem is less preferable than solving it here within the class itself

Comment: In my opinion, any class that uses this singleton is depending on an async operation, so I don't think there's a way to do this without them having to deal with that fact... If you figure out how to do this though please tell me, I'd be delighted to learn a better way.

Comment: @AugustoDiasNoronha: yes, thanks to one of our senior devs found an elegant solution. Posted below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some help, I found a good solution, that is both reliable and simple. The solution is to use count-down latch. Unfortunately there's no built-in class like that in Swift, but some implementations could be found online (for example: [this class from Uber](https://github.com/uber/swift-concurrency/blob/master/Sources/Concurrency/CountDownLatch.swift)). So this is a solution:

```
class DataProvider {

    public static let instance: DataProvider {
        // on first call wait here until callback is done
        // on subsequent calls, no need to wait since already initialized
        return internalInstance
    }
    private static let internalInstance = DataProvider()

    private let initLatch = CountDownLatch(1)

    private init() {
        initialize()
    }

    private func initialize() {
        Something.callAsynch { (result, error) in
            // instance becomes ready when this line is executed
            initLatch.countDown()
        }
    }

    public func doSomething() {
        initLatch.await()
        // this function should only run after asynch callback was executed
    }
}
```

So what does it do:

- the latch is set to 1 so any caller of `doSomething` will be suspended until latch is decremented to 0
- latch is only decremented to 0 in one place (init completion callback), hence nobody will proceed before initialization completed
- but after latch is set to 0, calling `doSomething` will not be delayed

Notes:

- This is a simplified model for problem and solution. In reality there are some other factors that may need to be taken into account, and would require other concurrency tools.
- In my case, the callers are non-interactive, hence I do want them to wait rather than be asynchronous. If callers were interactive, I'd let them deal with asynchronous nature of this class instead.

Comment: Thanks for tagging me, this is a pretty elegant solution!